# Swing layout ignores horizontal resize

Tags: java, swing, resize

I'm trying with Swing layouts to leave a gap above controls that's calculated from the current size of the window.  It basically works, except that the control only moves when the window is resized horizontally - if I resize vertically, it stays where it is - then resizing 1 pixel horizontally, it snaps into the correct place.  Can anyone explain why the resizing gets ignored when I'm only resizing vertically?

I've proved the at the componentResized () is still being called on vertical resizes, and that contentPane.getWidth () and contentPane.getHeight () still give the right values.  So the size of the Dimension is being set correctly, just being ignored.  Its like I need to put a call into contentPane.payAttentionToUpdatesSizesOfYourComponents (), but I can't find any method that does this.  contentPane.invalidate () has no effect.

Also noticed if I strip out the BorderLayout, and set the BoxLayout directly in the contentPane, then it works as I want.  However while that's fine for this tiny example, the real window I have this problem on has some components in a JPanel set at NORTH with a gap above, some components in another JPanel set at SOUTH with a gap below, and a BorderLayout was the only way I could get these to position correctly so I can't strip it out.

Any advice or suggestions would be welcome!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.Box.Filler;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public final class ResizeOnlyWorksHorizontally
{
    public static final void main (final String [] args)
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel ();
        frame.setContentPane (contentPane);

        contentPane.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());

        final JPanel top = new JPanel ();
        top.setLayout (new BoxLayout (top, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        contentPane.add (top, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Put a space, then a label below it
        final Dimension startSpace = new Dimension (0, 0);
        final Filler filler = new Filler (startSpace, startSpace, startSpace);
        top.add (filler);

        top.add (new JLabel ("Text"));

        contentPane.addComponentListener (new ComponentAdapter ()
        {
            @Override
            public final void componentResized (final ComponentEvent e)
            {
                // Just any calc based on contentPane width and height to demo problem
                final int calc = (contentPane.getWidth () + contentPane.getHeight ()) / 2;

                // Alter the size of the space above the label
                final Dimension newSpace = new Dimension (0, calc);
                filler.setMinimumSize (newSpace);
                filler.setPreferredSize (newSpace);
                filler.setMaximumSize (newSpace);
            }
        });

        frame.pack ();
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you need the following after the sizes are changed to make sure the layout manager is invoked:

```
filler.revalidate();
```

However that is NOT a good solution as your entire approach to the problem is wrong. You should not be manually calculating sizes of components like that. That is the job of a layout manager. So you need to rethink your layout stategy. Don't forget you can nest panels with different layout managers.

For example if you need a changing gap in the frame then you should probably use a BoxLayout and you can add "glue" to the start and end. Or maybe you can use a GridBagLayout because you can control how components resize based on the space available.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick reply - the filler.revalidate() works, I guess what I was missing was that while I was altering the constraints of the Filler, I needed to 'poke' that to force the resize to take effect, and not its container.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't let me put a long enough comment under your answer camickr :(  I wanted to add that after posting this I also found this, similar but not identical problem with resizing BorderLayouts, and they describe a similar situation of NORTH/SOUTH positioned controls not paying attention to vertical sizing - [Java Swing BorderLayout resize difficulties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267311/java-swing-borderlayout-resize-difficulties)

I'd tried based on the replies to that to use GridBagLayout, and did get that to work after a bit of effort.  Basically its a 1x5 grid layout then with cells containing (space I forcibly resize, controls, glue, more controls, space I forcibly resize), and this worked.

> > You should not be manually calculating sizes of components like that.

The only thing I'm manually setting the size of is the gap above+below the controls, all the controls themselves I'm letting the layout manager deal with.  The size of those gaps has to match a background image on the frame which is sized to the frame but preserving aspect ratio, so the width of that border isn't something the layout manager can figure out, the real code for the 'calc' bit in my SSCCE above is:

```
final int edge = Math.min (contentPane.getWidth () / 4, contentPane.getHeight () / 3);
final int imgHeight = edge * 3;
final int borderSize = (contentPane.getHeight () - imgHeight) / 2;
```

So if the user resizes the window to be wide, there's black borders left+right of the image, and borderSize = 0.  If the user resizes the window to be tall, there's black borders above+below the image, and I want the controls to avoid going there, so they always sit in the background image.

But thanks very much for the push in the right direction :)